# Xcode, last version, getting error on builds and archives

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

I am having an issue on my Xcode, lots of times I built or archives the project, I get this error :

> Process:               Xcode [2376] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               9.2 (13772) Build Info:
>   IDEFrameworks-13772000000000000~2 App Item ID:           497799835 App
>   External ID:       825038102 Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:           Xcode [2376]
>   User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2018-02-19 13:01:31.507 +0100 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.13.2 (17C88) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   86191C10-4328-FD41-CE74-B094E22BEFE9
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 510 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        45  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue:
>   -[XCWorkQueueCommandBuiltinInvocation startRunning]_block_invoke
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 9C40b Assertion
>   failed: (sizeBack == listSize), function
>   _has_code_signature_extended_attribute, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-13756/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/BuildTaskPlugIns/CoreBuildTasks/Translators/PBXCp/PBXCp.mm,
>   line 453.
>
> Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff57ec07c2 mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff57ebfcdc mach_msg + 60 2
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff30488a15
>   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff30487d67 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff304873d7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487 5   com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff2f794e26 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286 6
>   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff2f794b96
>   ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613 7   com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff2f794914 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   64 8   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff2da5ff5f _DPSNextEvent
>   + 2085 9   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff2e1f5b4c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044 10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit               0x000000010f84ff9a -[DVTApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 390 11 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff2da54d6d -[NSApplication run]
>   + 764 12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2da23f1a NSApplicationMain + 804 13  libdyld.dylib
>     0x00007fff57d7a115 start + 1
>
> Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: shared-compile-command-queue (QOS:
>   UNSPECIFIED) 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00007fff57ecb41a
>   read + 10 1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000122e9a7aa
>   -[XCWorkQueueCommandLocalSubprocessInvocation handleOutputFileDescriptorActivity] + 86 2
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x0000000122f094f3 -[Xcode3BuildTask
>   main] + 1042 3   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff3259b53e
>   -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 778 4   libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff57d40d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 5   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x00007fff57d53333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317 6
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff57d40d50
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8 7   libdispatch.dylib                0x00007fff57d53333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317 8
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff57d531d6
>   dispatch_block_perform + 109 9   com.apple.Foundation
>     0x00007fff3259754c __NSOQSchedule_f + 342 10  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x00007fff57d40d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 11  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x00007fff57d53e76 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472 12 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff57d4b6cb
>   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703 13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff57d42941 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515 14 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff57d426ed
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101 15  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff580051ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387 16 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff58004c4d start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: -[IDEExecutionEnvironment
>   initWithWorkspaceArena:] (QOS: UNSPECIFIED) 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff57ec9cee __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff58006662 _pthread_cond_wait + 732 2   com.apple.Foundation 
>     0x00007fff3264acf8 -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 896
>   3   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff3261b765
>   -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 296 4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation        0x000000010f12a9c4 -[DVTOperationGroup
>   main] + 66 5   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3259b53e
>   -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 778 6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x000000010f12a977 -[DVTOperationGroup start] + 110 7
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff32597567 __NSOQSchedule_f +
>   369 8   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff57d40d50
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8 9   libdispatch.dylib                0x00007fff57d53e76 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472 10 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff57d4b6cb
>   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703 11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff57d42941 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515 12 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff57d426ed
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff580051ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387 14 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff58004c4d start_wqthread + 13
>   ...

There are also several times, the built goes succesfully... is anyone sperimentig this issue ?

Comment: Just wondering if you ever managed to work through this. I'm experiencing this myself in Xcode 10.1.

Comment: It was my fault, I was working with file saved on NAS so It used to give me some errors for Internet Issue